# Как сделать так, чтобы програма понимала какое число больше

Tags: php

[image: таблица с оценками]
Надо чтобы эта програма выводила лучших учеников по среднему балу.

Вот код:

```
<?

    $inform=array(
        1=>array("Василь",12,"н",8,"н","н",10,10),
        2=>array("Маша",8,"","н","",4,"н",7),
        3=>array("Ирина","н",11,"","н",7,"",6),
        4=>array("Никита","",8,8,9,"","н",7),
        5=>array("Саша","н","н","н","",9,"н",7),
        6=>array("Коля",9,"",8,10,10,11,12),
        7=>array("Гриша",9,"","","","",7,"н"),
        8=>array("Оля","н","н","","",6,"",""),
        9=>array("Галя",4,5,"","н","н","н",5),
        10=>array("Тарас",10,10,8,"н",11,12,9));

    echo "<table border='1' width='400'>";
       echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Номер</th>";
            echo "<th>Им'я ученика</th>";
            echo "<th>1</th>";
            echo "<th>2</th>";
            echo "<th>3</th>";
            echo "<th>4</th>";
            echo "<th>5</th>";
            echo "<th>6</th>";
            echo "<th>7</th>";
            echo "<th>Сер.<br>бал</th>";
        echo "</tr>";   
        foreach ($inform as $key=>$st){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$key."</td>";
               $n=0;
               $sum=0;
                foreach ($st as $value){
                    echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
                    if($value>0) {
                    $sum=$sum+$value;
                        $n++;
                    }   
                }   
                $ser=$sum/$n;
                echo "<td>".round($ser,2)."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }   
    echo"</table>"; 


?>
```

Comment: Очевидно, что исправить ошибки в программе.

Comment: Нужна сортировка или один, два три лучших?

Comment: Надо чтобы програма вывадила тех у кого лучший средний бал (в данном случае у кого 10)  и таких 3. Значит програма должна выводить трьох таких учеников.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, если не менять особо ваш код, можно реализовать так, реализовал вывод всех по убыванию:

```html
<?php

 $inform=array(
  1=>array("Василь",12,"н",8,"н","н",10,10),
  2=>array("Маша",8,"","н","",4,"н",7),
  3=>array("Ирина","н",11,"","н",7,"",6),
  4=>array("Никита","",8,8,9,"","н",7),
  5=>array("Саша","н","н","н","",9,"н",7),
  6=>array("Коля",9,"",8,10,10,11,12),
  7=>array("Гриша",9,"","","","",7,"н"),
  8=>array("Оля","н","н","","",6,"",""),
  9=>array("Галя",4,5,"","н","н","н",5),
  10=>array("Тарас",10,10,8,"н",11,12,9));

 echo "<table border='1' width='400'>";

 echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th>Номер</th>";
  echo "<th>Им'я ученика</th>";
  echo "<th>1</th>";
  echo "<th>2</th>";
  echo "<th>3</th>";
  echo "<th>4</th>";
  echo "<th>5</th>";
  echo "<th>6</th>";
  echo "<th>7</th>";
  echo "<th>Сер.<br>бал</th>";
 echo "</tr>";   

 foreach ($inform as $key=>$st){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$key."</td>";
  $n=0;
  $sum=0;
  foreach ($st as $value){
   
   echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
   if($value>0) {
    $sum=$sum+$value;
    $n++;
   }   
   
  }   
  $ser=$sum/$n;
  echo "<td>".round($ser,2)."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  
  $forSort[] = [ 'score' => $ser, 'name' => $st[0] ];
 }   

 echo"</table>";

array_multisort($forSort, SORT_DESC);
echo '<h3>Результаты:</h3>';

foreach ($forSort as $value) {
 $max = ( isset($max) ) ? $max : $value['score']; //Записываем максимальное значение
 if ( $max > $value['score'] ) break; // Проверяем и выходим если значение меньше
 echo <<<END
 
 <br> $value[name] : $value[score]
 
END;
}
```

Comment: Да, в таком плане. Но надо чтобы высвечивались только те, у которых лучший средний бал (напоминаю это 10), а других у которых ниже средний бал не показывать

Comment: Ну так делайте теперь что хотите, у вас сортированный массив. Добавил пару строк. Теперь только лучшие.

Comment: Хорошо так и сделаю