# Надо завершить программу используя else

Tags: php

Надо сделать, чтобы если ты пишешь товар в блок, а такого товара нет, то чтобы программа выдавала "Такого товара нет".

Вот код:

```
<?
$fruit=array("Абрикос","Ананас","Алича","Айва","Вишня","Слива","Яблуко");
$priceFr=array(25,40,10,50,25,15,8);
$z=$_POST['z'];
$z1=$_POST['z1'];
$z2=$_POST['z2'];

for($i=0;$i<count($fruit);$i++){
   if($priceFr[$i]==$z){
      echo $fruit[$i]." ".$priceFr[$i]." грн<br>";
}else if($priceFr[$i]>=$z1 and $priceFr[$i]<=$z2){
      echo $fruit[$i]." ".$priceFr[$i]." грн<br>";
}
}

?>
```

http://394.itelit.top/PHP/t7/z1/index.php

Comment: вы сюда за готовыми решениями приходите? А когда их получаете, то даже элементарное [спасибо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746164/185343) написать не хотите?

Comment: Стоп. Почему же?

Comment: мне не известно, почему - перейдите по ссылке в комментарии выше, и посмотрите под данным для вас ответом, есть ли там "спасибо"? А ещё, вместо текста вы могли бы принять ответ, отметив его галкой -- но там ни первого, ни второго нет.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо вам. Так и сделал

Comment: Можно поставить в блоке else break

Comment: Спасибо. Так и попробую

Comment: Но если использовать break, то это выход из цикла

Comment: Ок. Тогда я понял. Щас попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всегда разделяйте вывод от логики, тогда всё будет понятнее:

```
$found = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($fruit);$i++){
 // В оригинальном коде вы ищете совпадение наименования или! цены
 // Вероятно, это не то, чего вы хотели
 if($priceFr[$i]==$z){
  $found[] = $i;
 } else if($priceFr[$i]>=$z1 and $priceFr[$i]<=$z2){
  $found[] = $i;
 }
}

if (empty($found)) {
  echo "Такого товара нет<br>\n";
} else {
  foreach ($found as $i) {
    echo $fruit[$i]." ".$priceFr[$i]." грн<br>\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Я просмотрел. И работает. Спасибо вам

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?
$fruit=array("Абрикос","Ананас","Алича","Айва","Вишня","Слива","Яблуко");
$priceFr=array(25,40,10,50,25,15,8);
$z=$_POST['z'];
$z1=$_POST['z1'];
$z2=$_POST['z2'];

for($i=0;$i<count($fruit);$i++){
   if($priceFr[$i]==$z){
      echo $fruit[$i]." ".$priceFr[$i]." грн<br>";
   }else if($priceFr[$i]>=$z1 and $priceFr[$i]<=$z2){
      echo $fruit[$i]." ".$priceFr[$i]." грн<br>";
      break;
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам. Но я нашёл правильный ответ